# Websockets between 2 servers?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, websocket

I wonder if it's possible to use websockets between 2 webservers instead of between a browser and backend?

Im running 2 node.js servers and want to exchange data between them.

Comment: I think it would be possible, the problem is that there isn't (as far as I know) a WebSocket client for node.js so you'd have to write the client yourself.

Comment: Defiantly create a TCP server/socket between the two from `net` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this helps https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node/tree/master/support/node-websocket-client

Answer (score 5):

Try to look at [node2node-socket.io](https://github.com/dotmaster/node2node-socket.io) or [Socket.io-node-client](https://github.com/remy/Socket.io-node-client) modules. However I would say that you should stick to built-in net module with pure sockets if you are communicating only between web servers.

Comment: Websockets were created due to browser limitations. With two servers you don't have the limitations which is why pure sockets is the better solution.