# HTTP vs Websockets with respect to overhead

Tags: optimization, node.js, websocket, overhead-minimization

I am building a file synchronization program (not unlike Dropbox) using node.js on both ends.  I need to have potentially thousands of clients requesting data at the same time.

Here is my current system:

- Server pushes notifications to client over a websocket (file has been updated)
- Client queues downloads and makes an HTTP request when idle

I will be serving data in compressed chunks of, say, 50 MB each, so the HTTP request overhead (headers) is negligible.

If I were to use websockets for requests **and** push notifications, would there be:

- Noticeable overall speed improvements? (reduced latency, authentication, etc.)
- Additional overhead on the server to keep connections open?
- Issues with pushing binary data?

I think I need to have notifications sent over a dedicated websocket because I don't want them to be queued on the server while a download is taking place (lots of overhead).

Note: **These websockets will be open long-term, as long as the client's system is on.**

EDIT: I will be using the websockets on a different http server on different ports in order to move them to different CPU cores. I could potentially have thousands (if not hundreds of thousands) of concurrent websockets open...

Comment: "using node.js on both ends" - so both, client and server, would have node.js installed? Client won't be a browser for example?

Comment: Yeah, no browser.  I'll have complete control over requests and responses.  It'll be a desktop app that runs in the background.  simple HTTP server, simple HTTP client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you intend to use node.js for both client and server then you should use native [net](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.5/api/net.html#net) module with pure sockets rather than WebSockets. Pure sockets are much better optimized for data transfer, especially binary. As far as I know browser WebSockets do not even support binary transfer yet.

Comment: I'll have to look into that. Are there any statistics or benchmarks comparing two equivalent servers under high load?

Comment: I don't about any benchmark comparing pure sockets with WebSockets, but there was a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509905/websockets-between-2-servers) on this topic recently.

Comment: Yeah, there are some pretty nice libraries, such as [socket.io-node](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node). If nobody posts any benchmarks or something more complete than your answer, I'll probably mark yours as correct.

Comment: You are definitely right about websockets not supporting binary transfer.  I think a regular TCP socket is what I'm looking for.  Thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: For clarity for future viewers, websocket _does_ support binary transfer but javascript has no binary type which makes it imposible to transfer binary data to browsers over websocket, but one can use websocket with a different client to transfer websockets.
see: http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/

Answer (score 3):

I was searching around for something else and I found this post that explains websockets pretty well:

http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/7/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket

Here are some pretty interesting parts from the article:

> Websocket enables you to have continuos communication in significantly less network overhead compared to existing solution.

And:

> During making connection with WebSocket, client and server exchange data per frame which is 2 bytes each, compared to 8 kilo bytes of http header when you do continuous polling.

For my use case (no browser), this seems like the optimal solution!  Now I just need to decide whether I want to have a single websocket or multiple websockets per client (I'm leaning towards a single one at this point).

I really hope this is useful to someone.  I'll leave this open for the time being.  I'll be attending a JS conference later this week, and if I learn anything more I'll add to this post.

For those of you who care about browser support, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML_5%29#Related_specifications).  It looks like WebKit is the only reliable engine that supports it (Chrome and Safari).

Comment: Hi tjameson, did things went well with you regarding the web-socket implementation of file transfer project?
I'm about to start an implementation of a similar project in Python in both server and client sides.
Practically speaking, is it a good practice to do it in websockets or shall I only use it for messaging and get the file transfer part done in HTTP instead? Let me know your ideas from your experience. Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using Python, I can only assume you want something easy and fast enough, which HTTP is. It offers a great structure and is well supported. For an Arduino project, where the data was pretty small, I implemented the WebSocket protocol without the HTTP handshake. It's pretty simple (one byte header, 1-8 bytes for message length) and HTTP is hard on Arduino. If you need raw speed, look into that, otherwise just stick with HTTP until you run into problems.